# Can't boot Windows 10 USB drive from Grub 2

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, grub

So I was experimenting with some Android X86 build on my NuVision Windows tablet and while doing so I must have allowed Grub to take over the boot process.

I am trying to reinstall Windows on the tablet but I can't get it to boot from the USB.

I've entered the grub command line and I figured out that the USB drive is on (hd0,msdos1) and I've checked the file structure of the newly baked Windows 10 USB boot drive on another computer. So I expected to be able to do something like :

```
 set root=(hd0,msdos1)
 chainloader /bootmgr.efi
 boot
```

and I should be off set. However, that didn't go as planned.

I've tried with all the following:

```
/bootmgr.efi
/efi/boot/bootx64.efi
/efi/microsoft/bootcdboot.efi
/efi/microsoft/bootcdboot_noprompt.efi
```

And I noticed that for the first one it says Invalid EFI file. However, for the other, it spits out some EFI information/hash that leads me to believe i did something right.

When I type `boot` though, all I get is `Unknown Error` so I guess I'm missing something but can't figure it out yet.

Anyone has any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to skip Grub using eFIT and boot the device's EFI console and from there tried to load up the EFI file manually. And I realized my mistake when I saw the more descriptive error message that this EFI console output.

It turns out I was trying to load a Windows 10 - 64 bit edition on a IA32 device. Switching to the appropriate build fixed everything and the device immediately recognized Windows on the USB drive this time, without the need to manually boot from CLI.